# questions on an Assembly Square fountain redesign

Tags: design

I'd like to reproduce the fountain posted [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=10230828736647079&set=gm.5972434769535667&idorvanity=679451402167390)
Can anyone identify the parts used to make the wide blue/water rims on the 2nd and bottom level?
Also, how do I attach the squiggly water bursts on the 3rd level?

[image: fountain]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/KpfqgdBt4uM), the squiggly water bursts are just held by friction - they're not clipped in to anything.

The blue layers are just normal dishes (of different sizes, of course).

Comment: thanks - I missed the youtube link.